# Can I join two Computer Portable like one?

Tags: windows, window, share, environment

I'm programmer, I work with two computer portable and I would to know if possible join each one like one computer to use one mouse for all and share environment and resource. I've installeted on each computer win 8. There is any way to share work?

Thank's,

RainJoker

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for all (nobody .-.) I found "Mouse without borders" is amazing program for windows!!!

TheRainJoker